Did the Buddha describe caste as "bigotry, oppression and vanity"?
I read the following on the internet:

The suttas describe many conditions in Indian society and the world in
general, but you won't find any teachings recommending monks or anyone
else practice bigotry, oppression and vanity.

Did the Buddha describe caste as "bigotry, oppression and vanity"? Please provide examples from the "suttas"?

Not explicitly but he shows on several occasions how dumb an obsession he thought it to be:

‘Ambattha, it is not from the standpoint of the attainment of unexcelled knowledge-and-conduct that reputation based on birth and clan is declared, nor on the conceit which says: “You are worthy of me, you are not worthy of me!” For wherever there is a giving, a taking, or a giving and taking in marriage, there is always this talk and this conceit... But those who are enslaved by such things are far from the attainment of the unexcelled knowledge-and-conduct, [100] which is attained by abandoning all such things!’

DN 3



“‘But do you know, masters, if the mother who bore you went only with a brahman, and not with a non-brahman?’
“‘No, master.’
“‘And do you know if the mothers of the mother who bore you—back seven generations of mothers—went only with brahmans, and not with non-brahmans?’
“‘No, master.’
“‘And do you know if the father who sired you went only with a brahman woman, and not with a non-brahman woman?’
“‘No, master.’
“‘And do you know if the fathers of the father who bore you—back seven generations of fathers—went only with brahman women, and not with non-brahman women?’
“‘No, master.’
“‘Do you know how there is the descent of an embryo?’
“‘Yes, master, we know how there is the descent of an embryo. There is the case where the mother & father have come together, the mother is fertile, and a gandhabba [the being about to be reborn] is standing present. The coming together of these three is the descent of the embryo.’
“‘But do you know for sure whether the gandhabba is a noble warrior, a brahman, a merchant, or a worker?’
“‘No, master.’
“‘That being the case, do you know who you are?’
“‘That being the case, master, we don’t know who we are.’"

MN 93



Yes. The following sutta implies that the caste system's prescribed duties is a form of oppression.

“But brahmin, did the whole world authorize the brahmins to prescribe
these four kinds of service?”
“No, Mister Gotama.”
“It’s as if they were to force a chop on a poor, penniless person,
telling them, “Eat this meat and pay for it!”
In the same way, the
brahmins have prescribed these four kinds of service without the
consent of those ascetics and brahmins.
MN 96


Reasonable effort however not conclusive. MN 96 says if it benefits them, the four castes can serve each other. In fact, in reality, they must serve each other, such as a merchant or aristocrat must look after the welfare of their workers & servants/slaves. Therefore, MN 96 does not appear to say the caste classifications are inherently oppressive. All MN 96 criticizes is how the Brahmins dictate how the four castes must be viewed.

In addition, MN 96 becomes a suspect fake sutta when it criticizes Brahmins who asserted they can only earn wealth from alms. Well, the Buddha's Vinaya also dictates the bhikkhus can only obtain livelihood from alms. MN 96 opens the Buddha up to allegations of hypocrisy. It gets worse because in the Buddha's response, he speaks a ridiculous irrelevant supramundane teaching about "noble spiritual wealth". The Buddha does not reply to explain how the four classes should earn their material wealth. These things makes MN 96 a suspect sutta because the Buddha appears unconvincing.

Also, if MN 96 is refuting the class distinctions, it is contradicting many other suttas, such as MN 98 and DN 31. MN 98 says a person's jati (social identity) is based upon their vocational actions (such as farming, trading, soldiering, ministering, etc) and DN 31 provides clear distinctions between the respective duties of respective classes. Also there are suttas such as AN 6.52 describing the goals of the different classes. In conclusion, the core message of MN 96 appears to be members of all four classes can become bhikkhus and attain the Noble Path and its Noble Wealth fruits.
